# Como detectar se o valor do JSpinner foi alterado?

Tags: java, swing

Eu quero realizar uma ação sempre que o valor do `JSpinner` for alterado. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta aplicar o evento [`ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) ao componente:

```
spinner.addChangeListener(e -> {
    //faça algo quando o valor alterar
});
```

Demonstração:

[image: demonstração do evento]